# $|x-2|$ as a factor of $|x^n-2^n|$ as a limit of function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, factoring

I haven't posted in a while but I do have a question on factoring a specific term out of a particular polynomial function and I'm stuck at some point in the process. Please, let's see so that my nightmares go away.

Say we seek to prove that $\:\lim_{x\to2}\large\:\frac{|x^n-2^n|}{x-2}$$\:=n2^{n-1}$

Thus, $\large\:|\frac{x^n-2^n}{x-2}-$$2n^{n-1}\large|$$\:=\large|\frac{x^n-2^n-(x-2)2n^{n-1}}{x-2}|$

$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:=\large|$$(x-2)\cdot\large\frac{x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}\cdot2+x^{n-3}\cdot2^2+.\:.\:.\:+x^2\cdot2^{n-3}+x\cdot2^{n-2}+2^{n-1}-n2^{n-1}}{x-2}|$

$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:=\small|x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}\cdot2+x^{n-3}\cdot2^2+.\:.\:.\:+x^2\cdot2^{n-3}+x\cdot2^{n-2}+2^{n-1}-n2^{n-1}|$

$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:=\small|x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}\cdot2+x^{n-3}\cdot2^2+.\:.\:.\:+x^2\cdot2^{n-3}+x\cdot2^{n-2}+(1-n)(2^{n-1})|$

Now, since we know $\:|x-2|\:$is a factor of$\:|x^n-2^n|\:$the big question becomes how could we use such a factor on :

$\small|x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}\cdot2+x^{n-3}\cdot2^2+.\:.\:.\:+x^2\cdot2^{n-3}+x\cdot2^{n-2}+(1-n)(2^{n-1})|\:$?

So that, we would use a simple restriction on$\:|x-2|<1\:$and then have a minimized$\:\delta(\epsilon)\:=\imath\eta f\{1,\frac{\large\epsilon}{\phi}\}\:$where we let$\:\phi :=\:$the multiple that is strictly larger than the multiple of $\:|x-2|\:$that we're looking for.

Thanks!

Comment: This is quite much simpler and I know how to prove the convergence, but I need a new term out $\small\:|x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}\cdot2+x^{n-3}\cdot2^2+.\:.\:.\:+x^2\cdot2^{n-3}+x\cdot2^{n-2}+(1-n)(2^{n-1})|\:$from a division or factoring by $\:|x-2|$

Comment: It might be helpful to regroup and use triangle inequality: $|x^{n-1}-2^{n-1}+2(x^{n-2}-2^{n-2})+2^2(x^{n-3}-2^{n-3})+\dots+2^{n-2}(x-2)|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $a≠0$:

\begin{align}
\dfrac{x^n-a^n}{x-a} - na^{n-1} &= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (x^ka^{n-k-1}-a^{n-1})\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a^{n-k-1} (x^k-a^{k})\\
\end{align}

Triangle inequality says:

$$\left|\dfrac{x^n-a^n}{x-a} - na^{n-1}\right| \le \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} |a^{n-k-1}||x^k-a^k|$$

If $|x-a|\le |a|$, then 
\begin{align}
|x^k-a^k|&\le|x-a|\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}|x|^j|a|^{k-j-1}\\
&\le |x-a||a|^{k-1}(2^k-1)
\end{align}

Finally, we have:

\begin{align}\left|\dfrac{x^n-a^n}{x-a} - na^{n-1}\right|& \le \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} |a^{n-k-1}||x^k-a^k|\\
&\le |x-a||a|^{n-2}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (2^k-1)\\
&\le |x-a||a|^{n-2}(2^n-n)
\end{align}

Let $\delta = \min(|a|,\dfrac{\epsilon}{|a|^{n-2}(2^n-n)})$

Comment: Awesome thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note:
The proof has been completely rewritten.

More generally,
you want to show that,
if $a > 0$
then
$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}
=na^{n-1}
$.

You have the right start:

$\frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}
=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k a^{n-1-k}
$.

What you need to show is that,
for $x$ close to $a$,
$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k a^{n-1-k}$
is close to
$n a^{n-1}$.

What makes this reasonable is that,
for $x$ close to $a$,
$x^k a^{n-1-k}$
is close to
$a^{n-1}$
so the sum of these
is close to
$na^{n-1}$.

To make this rigorous,
suppose
$|x-a| < c$,
where, eventually,
we will make $c$
as small as we need.
We certainly need
$c < a$.

Then
$-c < x-a < c$
or
$a-c < x < a+c$.

First,
we get an upper bound on the terms.

$\begin{array}\\
x^ka^{n-1-k}
&\lt (a+c)^ka^{n-1-k}\\
&= a^k(1+c/a)^ka^{n-1-k}\\
&= (1+c/a)^ka^{n-1}\\
\end{array}
$

We now use this lemma:

If $u > 0, v > 0,$
and
$uv < 1$
then
$(1+u)^v
< \frac1{1-uv}
$.
If $uv < \frac12$,
then
$(1+u)^v
< 1+2uv
$.

Proof:

If $uv \le \frac12$ then

$\begin{array}\\
(1+u)^v
&= e^{v\ln(1+u)}\\
&\le e^{vu}
\qquad\text{(since }\ln(1+u) < u)\\
&\le \frac1{1-uv}
\qquad\text{(since }e^x \le \frac1{1-x} \text{ for } 0 \le x < 1)\\
&\le 1+2uv
\quad\text{(since } \frac1{1-x}=1+\frac{x}{1-x}\le 1+2x)\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
if
$\frac{cn}{a} 
\le \frac12
$,
then
$(1+c/a)^k
\lt 1+\frac{2ck}{a}
$
so that
$x^ka^{n-1-k}
\lt (1+\frac{2ck}{a})a^{n-1}
$.

Summing,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^ka^{n-1-k}
&\lt \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (1+\frac{2ck}{a})a^{n-1}\\
&= na^{n-1}+2ca^{n-2}\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\\
&< na^{n-1}+cn^2a^{n-2}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
if
$cn^2a^{n-2}
< \epsilon$,
$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^ka^{n-1-k}
< na^{n-1}+\epsilon
$.

For a lower bound,

$\begin{array}\\
x^ka^{n-1-k}
&\ge (a-c)^ka^{n-1-k}\\
&= a^k(1-c/a)^ka^{n-1-k}\\
&= (1-c/a)^ka^{n-1}\\
\end{array}
$

We now use this lemma:

If $u > 0, v > 0,$
$uv < 1$,
and
$\frac{2uv}{1-u} < \frac12$,
then
$(1-u)^v
\gt 1-\frac{2uv}{1-u}
$.

Proof.

$\begin{array}\\
(1-u)^{-v}
&=(\frac1{1-u})^{v}\\
&=(1+\frac{u}{1-u})^{v}\\
&\le 1+\frac{2uv}{1-u}
\qquad\text{(by the lemma above)}\\
&= \frac{1-u+2uv}{1-u}\\
\text{so}\\
(1-u)^{v}
&\ge \frac{1-u}{1-u+2uv}\\
&= 1-\frac{2uv}{1-u+2uv}\\
&\gt 1-\frac{2uv}{1-u}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
if
$\frac{2cn}{a(1-c/a)} 
\le \frac12
$,
or
$\frac{2cn}{a-c} 
\le \frac12
$,

then
$(1-c/a)^k
\gt 1-\frac{2ck}{a(1-c/a)}
= 1-\frac{2ck}{a-c}
$
so that
$x^ka^{n-1-k}
\gt (1-\frac{2ck}{a-c})a^{n-1}
$.

Summing,
assuming in addition that
$a-c > \frac{a}{2}$
or
$c < \frac{a}{2}
$,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^ka^{n-1-k}
&\gt \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (1-\frac{2ck}{a-c})a^{n-1}\\
&= na^{n-1}-\frac{2ca^{n-1}}{a-c}\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\\
&\gt na^{n-1}-\frac{cn^2a^{n-1}}{a-c}\\
&\gt na^{n-1}-2cn^2a^{n-2}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
if
$2cn^2a^{n-2}
< \epsilon$
and
$c < \frac{a}{2}
$,
$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^ka^{n-1-k}
\gt na^{n-1}-\epsilon
$.

Comment: I rewrote it, maing it a lot simpler. There are also a couple of possible useful lemmas bounding $(1+u)^v$ and $(1-u)^v$.

Comment: How could I not appreciate the effort you're putting on
Thanks!